# c macro duplicate arguments

Tags: c, macros

I'm writing a tracer with function signature:

```
void AO_TRACE(int level, char *macrostring, uint16_t type, uint32_t argument1, uint16_t argument2);
```

and have useful macro for make string from macro

```
#define strmacro(s) #s
```

i'm calling my function like that:

```
AOCS_TRACE(LEVEL_TRACE,strmacro(TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE), TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE, tcount[0],0);
```

is it possible to write a macro to call function like that

```
AOCS_TRACE(LEVEL_TRACE,newmacro(TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE), tcount[0],0);
```

in other words write a macro which just placing a string representation of input and input itself. I've tried:

```
#define TRACE(s) #s, s
```

and

```
#define TRACE(s) (#s, s)
```

but it's doesnot work propertly

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5513206927214ff). Can you detail how it "does not work properly?"

Comment: stri = 0x420d000100010001 <Error reading characters of string.>

Forget to mention, i'm using msvc12. You example of usage looks exactly what i need

Comment: with #define TRACE(s) #s, s i' calling AOCS_TRACE function with args 3, TRACE(FOOBAR),1,2)

and in debugger i see that first argument is correct and all other args looks like garbage

Comment: Please don't put relevant information in comments where it's hard to read. [Edit] your question and add information there where it can be nicely formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is working fine.

Example code to show how:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define macro(s) #s,s
const int TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE= 123;
void AO_TRACE(int level, char *macrostring, uint16_t type, uint32_t argument1, uint16_t argument2) {
  printf("Level: %d, String: <%s>, Type: %d: Arg1: %d, Arg2: %d\n", level, macrostring, type, argument1, argument2);}
int main(){
  AO_TRACE(1, macro(TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE), 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs as expected

```
Level: 1, String: <TRACE_qtn_guidance_TCOUNT0_VALUE>, Type: 123: Arg1: 2, Arg2: 3
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Don't know why itis doesnot works for me now. Will debug it.